# Notation for a vector space: $(\mathbb{C}^\infty)^{\otimes L}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0412129v1.pdf), the authors use the notation $(\mathbb{C}^\infty)^{\otimes L}$, where $L$ is a constant, for a vector space, but they do not give a definition. They also implicitly introduce an inner product on that space that they don't define.

I suppose a simpler question would be: what exactly is the space $\mathbb{C}^\infty$? Then one could construct the original space using the tensor product.

I'm sure this is standard notation and I've just missed it somehow.

Thanks

Comment: It's an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (for example the space of finite sequences) tensorized $L$ times with itself.

Comment: $\Bbb C^{\infty}$ is $$\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb C\,,$$ in other words, it's a complex vector space with numerable basis. You can describe it as the space of complex sequences that are eventually $0$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Is there only one such space? Is the space countably or uncountably infinite?

Comment: What do you mean by "countably or uncountably infinite"?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I suppose I am asking whether the space has a countable basis or not, but I think your first comment implies that it does, if that's what you mean by numerable basis

Comment: @mjrussell: Usually such a space it taken to have a countable basis. But it's ambiguous and it could be any cardinality (and if the bases have different cardinalities, the spaces aren't isomorphic).